# Conditional formatting formula

Tags: formatting, conditional-statements, openoffice-calc

I have an OpenOffice Calc sheet containing a number of columns.  Two of the columns are:

1. D (Gender)
2. F (Nationality)

Now, I want to highlight all the records which have Gender=`Male` and Nationality=`UK`.

I tried the following but it did not work:

```
$D='Male' AND $F='UK'
```

Can you please provide me an example of a formula which I can use to do this in the Conditional Formatting menu?

Comment: I gave a point for the question, as the Help in LO Calc (version 4.3) is limited to this very limited instruction:
"If you select Formula is as a reference, enter a cell reference. If the cell reference is a value other than zero, the condition matches."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Highlight the data in row D, then from the conditional formatting menu, choose 'Format cells that contain', 'Cell value', 'Equal to',  ="Male". Select a format, 'OK', 'Apply', 'OK' and you're done.

Comment: The formula you need to combine both conditions if your columns have headers is =and(D2="Male";F2="UK"). You could use it in a separate column and apply conditional formatting to the new column. You may be able to use it directly in the conditional formatting 'formula' box but I don't know OpenOffice Calc well enough to give you the best advice how to do it.

Comment: Thanks irozak and Tom Sharpe :)

Answer (score 3):

Select the columns you wish to apply the highlighting to. In Format - Conditional Formatting, for Condition 1 select `Formula is` and enter:

```
AND($D1="Male";$F1="UK")
```

choose a Style, OK.